# Modifying size and style of thebibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I am using [an excellent poster template](http://gaelbn.com/scientific-poster-latex-template/) at the moment that I have found on the internet. However, there is a small section that I don't quite understand. It is

```
\let\olditem\item
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
    \subsubsection*{\sf\Large\refname}
    \let\par\relax
    \let\newblock\relax
    \normalsize

    \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{\olditem}%
    \inparaenum[1{.}]}{\endinparaenum}
```

I think I understand how this causes `\subsubsection*` to be used in place of the usual `\section*`.

I am less sure what the `\par\relax` and `\newblock\relax` do, since commenting them out does not change anything.

The line with `\inparaenum` seems to change `[1]` to `1.`.

The thing I don't understand is why this seems to get rid of all the line breaks, i.e.,

> [1] blabla
>
> [2] blablabla

changes to

> [1] blabla   [2] blablabla

The template is available under the link above, but I hope I copied out the relevant section. Thank you for your ideas!

Comment: The `inparaenum` environment (from `paralist`) indeed is designed to have a continuous enumeration  within a paragraph. If you want to change that, try replacing `inparaenum` with `asparaenum`.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for! If you like, you can add that as a proper answer and I'll accept.

Comment: No, thanks.  I think it's too specialised to be worth an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments.